# C - How to read a wav file format

Tags: c, io, wav

I'm trying to read a wav file in c, but still no results.
I have tried to read using `fread` and `fscanf`. I really have no idea what to do to read this file type.

This is my code in c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    long n, size;
    int i;
    int *ptr;

    fp = fopen("gundah.wav", "rb");

    /* Find end of file */
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);

    /* Get current position */
    n = ftell(fp);

    /* Get size of file */
    size = n;

    ptr = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    if(ptr == NULL)
        printf("memory not allocated\n");

    /* read the file and print it to the screen */

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

All i need is just read the file and then print it to screen.
Can someone please help me?

**EDIT:**
I want to read the bytes and see the result

Comment: What exactly do you want to print to the screen? Wikipedia has a page about the [WAV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV). Use that as a starting point to find out how to read the file.

Comment: you wanna print out the bytes?

Comment: really? i didn't say that i never try dude, i want to print the bytes @Kninnug

Comment: yes, that is exactly i wanna do, but some example seems too difficult, since they prefer to check the header, etc. I just wanna print the bytes, can you help me sir? @TLJ

Comment: `getc` will read a byte. Or `fread` will read a bunch of them, if you read into a char array.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check. Just give you a rough idea.

```
void printBytes(unsigned char* buff, int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(i%8 == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("0x%02x",buff[i]);
        printf("\t");

    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char buffer[1024];

    FILE *fp = fopen("test.wav", "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        size_t byte_read;
        // double check this
        do{
            byte_read = fread(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),1024,fp);
            printBytes(buffer, byte_read);
        }while(byte_read > 0)
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Certainly should be `fopen("test.wav", "rb");`

Comment: can you give me some advise about the LEN variable? is that the length of byte or the size of file?

Comment: I meant to say 1024. You have to do a lot of checking yourself. I didn't even run this code thru a compiler.